# Return the index of the last non empty object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

I am trying to get the index of last non empty name in my array of objects. I tried the code below:

```js
var myArray = [{'name':''},{'name':'b'},{'name':''}];
var last = myArray.reduce((acc, curr) => curr ? curr : acc);
console.log(myArray.lastIndexOf(last))
```

The log always displays 2. The output should be 1 since `name == 'b'` is not empty. How can I correct this code?

Answer (score 2):

`curr` is always an object in your case, and objects are always truthy. You should not check for the value of `curr`, but of `curr.name`.

```js
var myArray = [{'name':''},{'name':'b'},{'name':''}];
var last = myArray.reduce((acc, curr) => curr.name ? curr : acc);
console.log(myArray.lastIndexOf(last));
```

You could as an alternative also use `reverse` and `find`:

```js
var myArray = [{'name':''},{'name':'b'},{'name':''}];
var last = [...myArray].reverse().find(curr => curr.name);
console.log(myArray.lastIndexOf(last));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could easily use a traditional loop to do that

```js
 var myArray = [{'name':''},{'name':'b'},{'name':''}];
  
  function lastIndex(arr, ppty){
    // Start transversing the array from the rear
    // Improve your time complexity
    for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if(arr[i][ppty]){
        return i
      }
    }
    return false // Return false if it's not found
  }

const index = lastIndex(myArray, 'name') // This should give your answer

console.log(index)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this    for (let i = arr.length; i > 0; i--)  be    for (let i = arr.length-1; i >= 0; i--)

Comment: Yes.. I made an error there.. it should be arr.length - 1.. i will update it thanks

Comment: you are closer.. but don't you want to go all the way to index zero? for (let i = arr.length-1; i >= 0; i--)

Comment: An oversight on my end